# Backbone.js dynamic type model similar to T type in java

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I am updating to my earlier question based on the comment to get better understanding:

```
//Model's
        Student =  Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults: {
                name: ''
            }
        });

        Students =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Student,
            initialize: function(){
            },
            parse: function(resp) {
                return resp;
            }
        });

        Teacher = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                name : '',
                salary : ''
            }
        });   

        Teachers =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: Teacher,
            initialize: function(){
            },
            parse: function(resp) {
                return resp;
            }
        });

        /**
        * I Just need WrapperModel only single class instead of two so that when ever I 
        * make collection of this class I can dynamically bind the 'data' attribute to
        * either Teachers or Students
        */

        WrapperModelStudent = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                message : '',
                processingStatus : ''
            },
            initialize : function() {
                this.data = new Students([new Student({name: "Marry"}),
                                          new Student({name: "Susan"}),
                                          new Student({name: "Samanta"})
                                            ]);
            }
        });

        WrapperModelTeacher = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                message : '',
                processingStatus : ''
            },
            initialize : function() {
                this.data = new Teachers();
            }
        });

        WrapperModelStudents =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: WrapperModelStudent,
            initialize: function(){
            },
            parse: function(resp) {
                return resp;
            }
        });

        WrapperModelTeachers =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: WrapperModelTeacher,
            initialize: function(){             
            },
            parse: function(resp) {
                return resp;
            }
        });


        /**
        *Trying below 
        */
        /***
        * instead of using above two need to just use below one. How to do this??
        */
        WrapperModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
            defaults : {
                message : '',
                processingStatus : ''
            },
            initialize : function(obj) {
                this.data = obj;
            }
        });

        WrapperModelStudentsA =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: WrapperModel(new Students()),
            initialize: function(){
            },
            parse: function(resp) {
                return resp;
            }
        });     
        WrapperModelTeachersB =  Backbone.Collection.extend({
            model: WrapperModel(new Teachers()),
            initialize: function(){             
            },
            parse: function(resp) {
                return resp;
            }
        });




        wrapperModelStudent = new WrapperModelStudent({message:"success",processingStatus:"y"});        
        wrapperModelStudents = new WrapperModelStudents([wrapperModelStudent]);     

        wrapperModelTeacher = new WrapperModelTeacher({message:"success",processingStatus:"y"});
        wrapperModelTeachers = new WrapperModelTeachers([wrapperModelTeacher]);

        wrapperModel = new WrapperModel({message:"success",processingStatus:"y"});      
        wrapperModelStudentsA = new WrapperModelStudentsA([wrapperModel]);      
        wrapperModelTeachersA = new WrapperModelTeachersA([wrapperModel]);


        console.log(wrapperModelStudents);
        console.log(wrapperModelTeachers);
```

I am getting following error for wrapperModel and I am not able to create it's object.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'set' 
***************  backbone-min.js:10

g.Model 
***************  backbone-min.js:10

d 
***************  backbone-min.js:38
(anonymous function) sample.html:110
```

So is it possible to do in backbone.js??

Comment: the code should work fine. What problems are you getting ? you could also abstract it a bit more by passing class and initializing it inside the constructor as in `model: Model(CollectionA)` & `this.data = new obj()`

Comment: Do you have an use case that will show the use of a different interface to those collections? Otherwise dynamic typing is much about ignoring type until the last moment.

Comment: I tried that John but its giving me error. I have updated the code. let me know if I am making any mistake's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're overthinking it. The model attribute of Backbone Collection are not THAT useful. You basically won't need them if you're not fetching anything. If you are though, I think you missed something in [Backbone's doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-model):
"*A collection can also contain polymorphic models by overriding this property with a function that returns a model.*"

Oh, and your error comes from thoses lines:

```
model: WrapperModel(new Students()),
```

Now, why doesn't this work is pretty crystal clear but requires some knowledge about JavaScript objects//classes: *using a class as a function WONT create an object, therefore your context IS NOT the class NOR an instance of it*. In this case, the *this* will be the global object as your error reads, and Backbone needs an object context to work correctly.
You could also try `new WrapperModel(new Students())`. You'd have no error, but this wouldn't work. The model attribute expects a class.

tl;dr: your line of code doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Is there any I can achieve this in backbone.js or need to stick with whatever I was doing like having different WrapperModel class each time... Let me check the documentation once again